# AssertionConsumerService giving "Not HTTP POST Method"

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I've implemented the MitId login with your nuget package. It seems to work fine until we get redirected back to the AssertionConsumerService endpoint. There I get "Not HTTP POST Method" but with your code repo I do not... there everything works fine..

Now I'm wondering whether it might be an issue with the metadata Service Provider XML file, or the wrong issuer in appsettings.js or something else that is configurable... because the code is pretty much identical to your code examples....

Do you have any idea what the problem might be? Does the Issuer need to be registered in the MitId administration portal somewhere? I do not know how the Issuer is supposed to be configured.

I followed your step by step guide on how to implement and used you code example repos to test with and also to copy and tweak the code from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NemLog-in should use POST binding when calling back to the AssertionConsumerService endpoint.

It is configured in the SP metadata (your applications metadata):
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Controllers/MetadataController.cs#L48

The SP metadata is uploaded to NemLog-in. The SP metadata include issuer, certificate(s) and endpoints.

And the AssertionConsumerService endpoint in you application is set to accept POST messages:
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L57

Comment: It is using the Saml2PostBinding, it is identical to the code you just sent the link to, the AuthController

BUT, I'm now a bit confused about the MetadataController and its endpoints...

The way I understood your guide is that you have the login method (AuthController) which redirects you to NemLogin, there you login, NemLogin reads the metadata file that we provided them with and they redirect back to the AssertionConsumerService (the endpoint for that is in the metadata xml file that we sent and uploaded in NemLogin portal)
At what point are the MetadataController and its methods used?

Comment: The MetadataController and its methods is only used when you call it in a brower so download the metadata xml file. NemLog-in can sadly not call an metadata file online.

Comment: Hi
I just implemented it and realized that it's there just for us so we can easily create the metadata file that we can send for upload.
Ok, so my logic is sound, I understood it correctly. Then our issued must be in the metadata file and/or that something went wrong with the upload in the NemLogin admin page with that metadata file

Comment: yes there must be a mismatch somewhere